# How can I force all of a form's 'owned forms' to the front without giving them the focus?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a bunch of forms that I'm assigning an owning form to. These forms stay on top of their owning form after the user creates them. The trouble is, sometimes I want to change the owning form of these 'owned forms'. If the owning form changes though, it doesn't automatically bring the owned forms to the front.

I can't just use bring to front on all the owned forms, because I don't want them to steal the focus.

Is there a way to bring any form to the front without stealing the focus, or is there some function on the owning form that tells it to re-bring all its owned forms to the front?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using Win32 API `GetForegroundWindow()` to remember the current focused window, `BringToFront` all your windows and eventually `SetFocus` to that foreground windows.

Comment: I'm doing something similar now, I need a solution that will never give focus to the owned forms. Even the slightest focus might give an unsightly flash caused by the change in title bar and border to the focused color and back to the unfocused color again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not remember but you can try .Activate() function.